# с# Как в DateTimePicker заблокировать возможность выбора выходных

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно исключить выбор выходных, и, желательно праздников в DateTimePicker

Comment: Winforrms? WPF? Что-то другое? Угадать?

Comment: Возможность заблокировать на Winforms